# recordMyDesktop can't use jackd for audio

Tags: audio, video, recording, jack

If I try to have `recordMyDesktop` (technically `qt-recordMyDesktop`) capture audio via `jackd`, when I hit `record` it immediately stops with the message:

```
recordMyDesktop has exited with status: 4352
Description: Port registration/connection failure
```

Both `recordMyDesktop` and `jack_lsp` can see the various audio channels/ports, and I fixed a problem causing `jack_lsp` to give a `cannot lock down XYZ byte memory area`, so I know that's not the problem.

**EDIT**: In `qt-recordMyDesktop-crash.log` are these lines:

```
jack_client_new: deprecated
Cannot connect input port recordMyDesktop-3950:input_1 to system:playback_2
```